# Changing the default parameters of new meshes

Tags: modeling

In 2.79 it was easy to change the default parameters of new meshes added to a scene, e.g. number of edges on a UV sphere. In 2.82 I have been tearing my hair out trying to find similar options. Have they disappeared?

Comment: no, it's the Operator box, on the bottom left, it may be folded, you can also display it with F9

Comment: Many thanks Moonboots. Sanity restored. I'm sure I'll get to love the 2.8 series....eventually!